# Is it possible to use pipenv for django-cookiecutter?

Tags: django, python-3.x, pipenv, cookiecutter-django

I know the docs specify virtualenv, but thought I would try:

```
pipenv install -r path/to/local_requirements.txt
```

It fails when trying to instal rcssmin==1.0.6 and rjsmin==1.0.12. It also tells me that I need to install Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 but it's already installed on my system. I'm new to cookiecutter so these issues could be unrelated.  Error message below.

```
$ pipenv install -r requirements/local.txt
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: C:\Users\Jim Wombles\dev\PAMG\Pipfile
Using c:\python36\python.exe (3.6.6) to create virtualenv...
Already using interpreter c:\python36\python.exe
Using base prefix 'c:\\python36'
New python executable in C:\Users\JIMWOM~1\VIRTUA~1\PAMG-G~1\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Setting project for PAMG-GBO_NxgA to C:\Users\Jim Wombles\dev\PAMG

Virtualenv location: C:\Users\Jim Wombles\.virtualenvs\PAMG-GBO_NxgA
Creating a Pipfile for this project...
Requirements file provided! Importing into Pipfile...
Pipfile.lock not found, creating...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Updated Pipfile.lock (582bd7)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (582bd7)...
An error occurred while installing rcssmin==1.0.6! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing rjsmin==1.0.12! Will try again.
  ================================ 83/83 - 00:01:04
Installing initially failed dependencies...
Collecting rcssmin==1.0.6 ----------- 0/2 - 00:00:00
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e2/5f/852be8aa80d1c24de9b030cdb6532bc7e7a1c8461554f6edbe14335ba890/rcssmin-1.0.6.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: rcssmin
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for rcssmin: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for rcssmin: finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command c:\users\jimwom~1\virtua~1\pamg-g~1\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\JIMWOM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h2db57b0\\rcssmin\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\JIMWOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-r35c5nc9 --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  copying .\rcssmin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

  running build_ext
  building '_rcssmin' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

  ----------------------------------------
  Running setup.py clean for rcssmin
Failed to build rcssmin
Installing collected packages: rcssmin
  Running setup.py install for rcssmin: started
    Running setup.py install for rcssmin: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command c:\users\jimwom~1\virtua~1\pamg-g~1\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\JIMWOM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h2db57b0\\rcssmin\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\JIMWOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-x417vnjs\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\users\jimwom~1\virtua~1\pamg-g~1\include\site\python3.6\rcssmin:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    copying .\rcssmin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

    running build_ext
    building '_rcssmin' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

    ----------------------------------------

  Failed building wheel for rcssmin
Command "c:\users\jimwom~1\virtua~1\pamg-g~1\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\JIMWOM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h2db57b0\\rcssmin\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\JIMWOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-x417vnjs\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\users\jimwom~1\virtua~1\pamg-g~1\include\site\python3.6\rcssmin" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\JIMWOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h2db57b0\rcssmin\

     ================================ 0/2 - 00:00:04
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly.

No.

> As far as I know, pipenv utilizes Pipfile "standard "under the hood where the latter doesn't support arbitrary requirements sections except for [packages] and [dev-packages], which is an obstacle for us since cookiecutter-django natively supports test and potentially other environments as well.

[Issue 1425](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/issues/1425)

However, it would be possible to fork it and update to use pipenv.